# Extra space around a div container inside JQM content

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am placing a div container inside the jquery mobile page inside a content div.  The code is as below.

CSS code

```
.his_outercontainer{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  height:50px;
  display: table;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class='his_outercontainer'>
      hello I am inside
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I see as below. Why there is extra space around the inner div (his_outercontainer)?

[image]

Comment: Your are missing a `</div>` at the end

Comment: Sorry, its a typo.  Corrected now.

Comment: You're not concerned about the margin that's in your <h1> tags are you?

Comment: I am only worried on the space outside the 1px border.  It should be fit with the screen.

Comment: Then there's some code that you haven't provided us because this is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/vee827md/1/

Comment: Hi, I use jQuery and JQM.  Refer http://jsfiddle.net/vee827md/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your .ui-content has a padding of 1em. This is what happens when you remove it: http://jsfiddle.net/vee827md/3/

```
.ui-content { padding: 0px;
}
```

I should mention that the padding was automatically added by jquery mobile css.